# Add Multiprocessing for livestream in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocess

I have created a python program, which receives the live video feed from a receiver and processes it using OpenCV. The processed video is simultaneously displayed as output. I am attaching the code for the same herewith.

```
import cv2
import queue
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import time
import threading

q=queue.Queue()

def Receive():
    print("start Receive")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    q.put(frame)
    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        q.put(frame)

def Display():
     print("Start Displaying")
     while True:
         if q.empty() !=True:
            frame=q.get()
# Barcode processing part #
            barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
            for barcode in barcodes:
                x, y , w, h = barcode.rect
                barcode_info = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
                print(barcode_info)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
                cv2.putText(frame, barcode_info, (x + 6, y - 6), font, 2.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
# Displaying the frames # 
            cv2.imshow("Drone Stream", frame)
         if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1=threading.Thread(target=Receive)
    p2=threading.Thread(target=Display)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

The process that I mentioned above is **Barcode scanning** and I have used **Multithreading**. Due to this, the output video i.e. **Livestream** is fast but there is a lag between the input video time and output video time. How do we create a separate function for barcode scanning, process the input frames from the **Receive** function and display it using **multiprocessing**?

Comment: why not try http://www.valkka.fi

Comment: How do we use that in windows?

Comment: uh.. sorry.  not avail in windows